# Replace spaces with dash and copy into new column

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have table named "city" with column named "city_name" with about 200 records.

I have created another colum named slugs where I want to copy all the records from "city_name" in the same row with spaces replaced with dash - and lowercase.

How can I achieve this via phpmyadmin.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to do this via the following query:

```
UPDATE city SET slugs=LOWER(REPLACE(city_name, " ", "-"))
```

Breaking this down, we're using `REPLACE` to swap all instances of " " with "-" in the existing `city_name` column, and then passing the result of this to the `LOWER` function (to convert the data to lower case) before setting the `slugs` field with this value.

Depending on how "clean" your data is, you might also want to TRIM the data (to remove any leading or trailing spaces in the `city_name` field) before you apply the REPLACE as such:

```
UPDATE city SET slugs=LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(city_name), " ", "-"))
```

Incidentally, if you've not used (My)SQL much I'd recommend a read of the [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) manual page - the time you spend on this now will more than repay itself in the future.

Comment: Thanks it was nice and easy. Just found out that there are also some , in the s_name along with space how can I replace thos , in the slugs column now?

Comment: @Jay Er... what? You can use the logic above to replace spaces with dashes in any column. (You can also update a column with a version of that column with no spaces, if that makes sense based on your data.) i.e.: `UPDATE city SET column_a=LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(column_a), " ", "-"))`.

Comment: Oh sorry for not eplaining my query. I meant apart from spaces there were also some , commas in the city name. as the query above have replaced the spaces with dashes. How can I replace the commas with dashes too  with this query       UPDATE city SET slugs=LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(city_name), " ", "-"))   thanks

Comment: @Jay Change the `REPLACE(TRIM(city_name), " ", "-"` to `REPLACE(TRIM(city_name), ",", "-"`. Incidentally, if you don't start reading the manual, you'll never learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05bb6/1)

MYSql documentation for function  [LOWER(str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) and [REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE city SET slugs = LOWER(REPLACE(city_name," ", "-"));
```